# When Write text on image - found image big size

Tags: vb.net

When Write  text on image - found image  big size
Origanl Picture : 32 KB
After Add text on Picture : 500 KB

```
   On Error Resume Next
    My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(DbPath + "\Pictures\" + "orign" + ".jpg")
    PictureBox2.Image.Save(DbPath + "\Pictures\" + "orign" + ".jpg", Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
    'End If
    Dim bmp = Bitmap.FromFile(DbPath + "\Pictures\" + "orign" + ".jpg")
    'Dim bmp = Bitmap.FromFile("orig.jpg")
    Dim newImage = New Bitmap(bmp.Width, bmp.Height + 80)

    Dim gr = Graphics.FromImage(newImage)
    gr.Clear(Color.White)
    gr.DrawImageUnscaled(bmp, 0, 0)
    gr.DrawString(MigraID.Text & Space(1) & MigraName.Text & Space(1) & IqamaNum.Text & Space(1) & DatePicH.Text,
     New Font("Arial", 27),
    New SolidBrush(Color.Black), New RectangleF(0, bmp.Height, bmp.Width, 80))
    bmp.Dispose()
    gr.Dispose()

    newImage.Save(DbPath + "\Pictures\" + MigraID.Text + ".jpg")
    PictureBox2.Image = Image.FromFile(DbPath + "\Pictures\" + MigraID.Text + ".jpg")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you don't specify the format, the default is "png". From [Image.Save Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.save?view=netframework-4.7#System_Drawing_Image_Save_System_String_)

> If no encoder exists for the file format of the image, the Portable Network Graphics (PNG) encoder is used.

So you need to specify your format:

```
newImage.Save(DbPath + "\Pictures\" + MigraID.Text + ".jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg)
```